# Exercise 1-18 K&R. How am i supposed to delete a blank?

Tags: c

I've been reading this book for over 2 weeks now and this is as far as I got (pretty slow, right?) anyways this is what I did:

I get this when trying to compile with eclipse

```
Building file: ../main.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.c"
../main.c: In function ‘erasewhites’:
../main.c:59:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
 }
 ^
../main.c:59:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
```

**line 59 is the one that says "to[i] = from [i]"**
What i tried to do was to read and copy it to a vector, then copy that vector into a new one without the white spaces and tabs and then if it was not an empty line, main function was supposed to print it. I was looking for this error but the only thing i found is that there is a return missing, which i already have thought but it's a void function (copy (to [], from []) ) and i tried writing before the } token return ; and return 0 ; but keep getting the same error
 Is the idea close to what the exercise asks for?
 ( Exercise 1-18. Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input, and
to delete entirely blank lines. )
Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
#define BLANK 1
#define NOT_BLANK 0

int getlinea (char s [], int lim);
void copy (char to [], char from []);
int erasewhites (char s[], int len);

int main (void){
    char palabra [MAXLINE];
    int len;
    while ( (len = getlinea (palabra, MAXLINE) ) >= 0)
        if (len > 0)
            printf ("%s\n",palabra);
    return 0;
}

int getlinea (char s[], int lim){
    int i, c, len;
    char aux[MAXLINE];
    for ( i=0; ( c = getchar () )!= EOF && c != '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)
        aux[i] = c ;
    if (c == EOF)
        return -1;
    if ( ( len = erasewhites ( aux, i) ) > 0 )
        copy ( s , aux );
    else
        return 0;
    return len;
}

int erasewhites (char s[], int len){
    int state = BLANK;
    while (len > 0 && state == BLANK){
        if ( s[len] != 32 && s[len] != '\t' )
            state = NOT_BLANK;
        else
            --len;
    }
    if ( len >= 0 )
        s[len+1] = '\0';
    else
        return 0;
    return len;
}

void copy ( char to[], char from [] ){
    int i;
    for ( i = 0 ; from [i] != '\0' ; ++i)
        to [i] = from [i] ;
    to [i+1] = '\0';
}
```

i erased the commented lines and it compiled... that was weird, this is what terminal returns when i go

$ ./program < main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>td
#define MAXLINE 1000
#define BLANK 1 1000
#define NOT_BLANK 00
int getlinea (char s [], int lim);
void copy (char to [], char from []);
int erasewhites (char s[], int len);;
int main (void){(char s[], int len);;
    char palabra [MAXLINE];], int len);;
    int len;abra [MAXLINE];], int len);;
    while ( (len = getlinea (palabra, MAXLINE) ) >= 0)dԁ
        if (len > 0)= getlinea (palabra, MAXLINE) ) >= 0)dԁ
            printf ("%s\n",palabra);alabra, MAXLINE) ) >= 0)dԁ
    return 0;("%s\n",palabra);alabra, MAXLINE) ) >= 0)dԁ
}return 0;("%s\n",palabra);alabra, MAXLINE) ) >= 0)dԁ
int getlinea (char s[], int lim){, MAXLINE) ) >= 0)dԁ
    int i, c, len;har s[], int lim){, MAXLINE) ) >= 0)dԁ
    char aux[MAXLINE];s[], int lim){, MAXLINE) ) >= 0)dԁ
    for ( i=0; ( c = getchar () )!= EOF && c != '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
        aux[i] = c ;c = getchar () )!= EOF && c != '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    if (c == EOF)c = getchar () )!= EOF && c != '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
        return -1;F)c = getchar () )!= EOF && c != '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    if ( ( len = erasewhites ( aux, i) ) > 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
        copy ( s , aux );whites ( aux, i) ) > 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    elsey ( s , aux );whites ( aux, i) ) > 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
        return 0;, aux );whites ( aux, i) ) > 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    return len; aux );whites ( aux, i) ) > 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
}return len; aux );whites ( aux, i) ) > 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
int erasewhites (char s[], int len){) > 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    int state = BLANK;ar s[], int len){) > 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    while (len > 0 && state == BLANK){{) > 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
        if ( s[len] != 32 && s[len] != '\t' ) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
            state = NOT_BLANK;& s[len] != '\t' ) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
        elsete = NOT_BLANK;& s[len] != '\t' ) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
            --len;= NOT_BLANK;& s[len] != '\t' ) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    }   --len;= NOT_BLANK;& s[len] != '\t' ) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    if ( len >= 0 )LANK;& s[len] != '\t' ) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
        s[len+1] = '\0';NK;& s[len] != '\t' ) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    elseen+1] = '\0';NK;& s[len] != '\t' ) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
        return 0;= '\0';NK;& s[len] != '\t' ) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    return len; '\0';NK;& s[len] != '\t' ) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
}return len; '\0';NK;& s[len] != '\t' ) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
void copy ( char to[], char from [] ){) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    int i;py ( char to[], char from [] ){) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
    for ( i = 0 ; from [i] != '\0' ; ++i)) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
        to [i] = from [i] ;i] != '\0' ; ++i)) 0 )= '\n' && i < lim-1 ; ++i)��0)z�
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are compiling this file? It does not have line 59, and `erasewhites` has an unconditional `return`.

Comment: That code compiles with no warnings or errors and only has 53 lines, so `../main.c` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: thx @user3386109 the 59th line was the one i included with "strong", because i didnt include the first 6 lines that eclipse adds as comments
 you were right though, when i deleted the commented lines that eclipse added it compiled correctly: i updated the question,
@ dasblinkenlight what do you mean with erasewhites has an unconditional return?

Comment: The `copy` function copies until it reaches the `'\0'`. It then needs to write a `'\0'` at the end of the string. So after the loop, you need `to[i] = '\0';`

Comment: thx for the reply @user3386109 
what about line 43:  s[len+1] = '\0'; ?

EDIT: you were right, THX!!!! Don't know how to upvote.

Comment: Yes, line 43 puts a `'\0'` at the end of `aux`, but then you `copy(s, aux)` and `copy` doesn't put a `'\0'` at the end of the output string `palabra`.

Comment: Yes @user3386109 i edited that answer, you were right, it keeps giving me strange characters though... i edited the original question again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exercise 1-18 in K&R The C Programming Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083904/exercise-1-18-in-kr-the-c-programming-language)